# Integrating SVN with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, tfs

Is there any recommendable solution to integrate SVN with TFS 2013 in a sense that SVN is being used for source control and TFS for work item tracking?

For example, it should be possible to link commits in SVN to work items in TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Integration with Bug Tracking Systems / Issue Trackers`: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html

> It is very common in Software Development for changes to be related to
>   a specific bug or issue ID. Users of bug tracking systems (issue
>   trackers) would like to associate the changes they make in Subversion
>   with a specific ID in their issue tracker. Most issue trackers
>   therefore provide a pre-commit hook script which parses the log
>   message to find the bug ID with which the commit is associated. This
>   is somewhat error prone since it relies on the user to write the log
>   message properly so that the pre-commit hook script can parse it
>   correctly.
>
> TortoiseSVN can help the user in two ways:
>
> 1. When the user enters a log message, a well defined line including the
>      issue number associated with the commit can be added automatically.
>      This reduces the risk that the user enters the issue number in a way
>      the bug tracking tools can't parse correctly.
> 2. Or TortoiseSVN can highlight the part of the entered log message which
>      is recognized by the issue tracker. That way the user knows that the
>      log message can be parsed correctly.
>
> When the user browses the log messages, TortoiseSVN creates a link out
>   of each bug ID in the log message which fires up the browser to the
>   issue mentioned.

Go through mentioned URL for detailed description.

Comment: Thank you Ivan! I will go through this and check if it works for us.

Answer (score 0):

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html describes how to configure folders in TortoiseSVN to do a one-way integration between file versions committed in TortoiseSVN, and work items in TFS.   When a developer commits the file version, he/she is prompted for the TFS work item number (which works fine if the developer knows the number).  It even creates a link to the TFS work item in the Revision Log of the file in TortoiseSVN.  However, it does not display a list of work items for the developer to choose from, nor is there any link in the TFS work item going back to the committed file version in TortoiseSVN.  (It is possible to write an issue tracker plug-in for TFS to do this, but all the plug-ins I have found on the internet seem to be for older versions of TFS.)

This integration will insert the bug number into the Revision Log of committed source files, and will add a link from the log to the selected bug in TFS.  Although you make this change inside your working copy, it will apply to the same folder in other working copies once those working copies have been updated.

To associate a folder tree in TortoiseSVN to TFS:
1. Right-click on the folder in your working copy.  This should be at the apex of the folder tree you want to associate with a project in TFS.  Select TortoiseSVN > Properties.
2. On the Properties - TortoiseSVN window, check to see whether there are any bugtraq properties for this folder.  If not, click New > Bugtraq (issue tracking integration).
3. The Edit Bugtraq Properties - TortoiseSVN window opens.
   a. For Issue tracker URL, specify the URL to your work items:
      http://tfs_server_name:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TFS_Project_Name/_workitems?id=%BUGID%&_a=edit
   b. Next, place a check in the "Remind me to enter a bug-ID" checkbox.
   c. For Message Pattern, specify something like:
      TFS Work Item: %BUGID%
   d. For Message Label, specify something like:
      TFS Work Item:
   e. For "Bug-id is", specify Numeric.
   f. At the bottom of the window, place a check next to "Apply property recursively".  Click OK.
4. Back on the Properties - TortoiseSVN window, verify that the bugtraq properties have been added and click OK.
5. Remember to perform an SVN Update and SVN Commit on the folder after changing its bugtraq properties.

The bugtraq properties that implement this one-way integration between SVN and TFS are built into Apache Subversion and so should work for SVN even if you are not using the TortoiseSVN user interface.